# How to Find MTD (Month To Date) by category for given data using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We need to calculate MTD on the given set of data :

Input:

```
Amount       Date     Cat
2540     01/04/2017    C
2396     01/04/2017    D
3659     01/04/2017    A
458      02/04/2017    D
2639     02/04/2017    B
1258     02/04/2017    A
856      02/04/2017    D
6987     03/04/2017    C
7965     03/04/2017    B
```

How we can calculate MTD on this Data

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `groupby` and `sum` using `dt.strftime('%b')` to get the Month, you could also use `dt.month` to get the numerical name of the Month.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b'),'Cat'])['Amount'].sum()


Date  Cat
Feb   A      1258
      B      2639
      D      1314
Jan   A      3659
      C      2540
      D      2396
Mar   B      7965
      C      6987
Name: Amount, dtype:
```

---

```
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.month,'Cat'])['Amount'].sum()

    Date  Cat
    1     A      3659
          C      2540
          D      2396
    2     A      1258
          B      2639
          D      1314
    3     B      7965
          C      6987
```

Comment: Getting the error  -  AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.